# Visual studio 2010 preview error?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm working on building an application with visual studio 2010. I make changes on the application; in the preview window I can see them. But when viewing on the browser there are not there. I have tried to reload the page on the browser but there still no change. I have also tried restarting visual studio and my computer  and it does not work. What can I do to fix this error?

Comment: Try cleaning the solution... Right click on the solution, and click on clean - see if that helps.

Comment: I don't have the option of clean. I'm using Visual studio 2010 version 10.0.

Comment: I'm using Visual studio 2010 premium. The bin Folder it holds the AjaxControlToolkit.dll; which i'm using for the :  <asp:HtmlEditorExtender ID="HtmlEditorExtender1"  runat="server"  
        TargetControlID="TextBox1" EnableSanitization="False">
    </asp:HtmlEditorExtender>

Answer (score 0):

It might be that files "are being used by another process". Try to close your solution and delete all "bin" and "obj" folders in your projects that are included in your solution. Then open your solution again, execute "Clean solution" and build it again.

[image]

Comment: I clean all folder in the Bin, But it still does not work. Plus I don't have clean Solution in the Build tab. It's there a way to update the version I'm using. Maybe It will give me the option to clean solution.

Comment: Did you try clearing browser cache? Hitting CTRL + F5 in the browser? Did you set the project to be built, and files placed somewhere other than the BIN folder? Also, check that when you build the project, the files in the BIN folder have a recent time and date...

Comment: If I do this:        <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>

      <div style="text-align: center; display: inline-block; width: 700px"> 

    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"    Width="400px" Height="300px" 
     BackColor="#3366FF" BorderStyle="Double" ForeColor="#0033CC"></asp:TextBox>

       </div>
   
 
    <asp:HtmlEditorExtender ID="HtmlEditorExtender1"  runat="server" Enabled="true"  
     EnableSanitization ="false" TargetControlID="TextBox1" >
    </asp:HtmlEditorExtender>

Comment: It will show on the preview window correct. but not on the fireFox browser. now if I change the div align= "center" it will show correct on the browser but it will also give a a warning on VS.